# Python Infinite While Loop Crashing Mac

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I have a python script with a loop such as

```
while True:
    #do something here
```

Whenever i run it, it will crash the mac.
The mac runs Mac OS X 10.6.5 and python 2.6.1

Comment: @giodamelio: I have exactly the same spec, except that I use macport's python distribution and It does not crashes for me. It is possible that what you are doing inside the loop crashes it. Can you publish the crash report / code that you execute inside while loop.

Comment: Does this result in a kernel panic or a hung GUI?

Comment: @pyfunc I have tested it with just a simple print command so i dont think it can be that.

Comment: I thought Macs could finish infinite loops in five seconds?

Comment: What is the crash?  What is the error message?  Is it something like `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` or something like `Traceback (most recent call last): File <file>, line #, in <module>`?

Comment: @giodamelio: er.. which one, do you get a message at the top of the screen saying "Kernel panic" and a bunch of other weird text?

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield crash as in the computer freezes up then i have to restart to get it to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can write any infinite loop and it causes a crash, then you either have a problem with your OS or your Python (since this doesn't normally cause a crash). Try out the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) Python distribution and hopefully you won't have the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your computer is overheating when you let it run on 100% CPU for too long. The solution then would be make sure the fan on your CPU works or to get a better one installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say Python 2.6.1 with OS X 10.6, I assume you are using the Apple-supplied Python 2.6.  If your machine is 64-bit capable, that Python will by default run in 64-bit mode which could have an impact on stack-related issues.  You could try running in 32-bit mode and see if the same thing happens; you can do that by invoking Python this way:

```
$ arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.6
```

You could also try installing the most recent Python 2.6 (2.6.6) using the python.org installer for OS X [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/).  Note: that Python is 32-bit only.  (By the way, Python 2.7 is now current.  If you can reproduce the problem with it, you should open an issue on the [Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/).)